# How to use multiple language routes with node and i18n?

Tags: node.js, express, internationalization, multilingual

I am building a simple website and would like the links to be translated.

Ex:

- about-us / a-propos-de-nous

Currently, I've noticed that to set the language with i18n, you need to redirect the user in order for it to catch on by doing something like:

```
app.get('/fr', (req, res) => {
    i18n.setLocale('fr');
    res.cookie('i18n', 'fr');
    res.redirect('/');
});
```

But how would that work if a user visit the following urls directly?

```
app.get(['/about-us', '/a-propos-de-nous'], (req, res) => {
    // How do I set the proper locale here? I can't do any redirect otherwise
    // I'll be caught in a redirect loop.
    res.render('about-us');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the requested path from req.url, you could check which one it was and set the language accordingly.

```
app.get(['/about-us', '/a-propos-de-nous'], (req, res) => {
  if(req.url === '/about-us') {
    i18n.setLocale('en');
    res.cookie('i18n', 'en');
  } else if(req.url === '/a-propos-de-nous') {
    i18n.setLocale('fr');
    res.cookie('i18n', 'fr');
  }

  res.render('about-us');
});
```

You could also prefix the path like `example.com/fr/a-propos-de-nous`, which would make it a little easier to extract the language from the request.

Comment: As I explained in the post, i18n requires that you do a redirect after setting the language (or at least, that is the only I can make it work). I've tried this solution and it unfortunately failed.